# Specify meta data for pgsql dml action

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible that embed/set some meta data(comment) with any postgresql dml action such as update?
Case study: assume I have table `foo` and `bar`, now I have a trigger on table `foo` which just rejects/denies any update operation for `bas` and `meh` columns.
And now I have a trigger on `bar` table, and I like to update `bas` and `meh` columns of `foo` table.
I'm thinking about checking a metadta/signal from the fired event in `foo` trigger in order to either reject or accept the update, maybe something like `if (<<has_specific_meta_data>>) then /*let update*/...`
For example mark the event for the trigger that is coming from a friend `bar` trigger.
Beside the metadata I'm thinking about, is there any other solution about this?
pgsql 9.3_x64@a_linux_guy

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't really. You can (ab)use GUCs for this, but it's fragile and likely to permit actions you didn't intend as well, because it's effectively setting a global variable.

In this specific situation it sounds like you should be able to do it with permissions. Don't grant `UPDATE` on `foo(bas)` or `foo(meh)` to the user who runs queries. Make the trigger on `bar` `SECURITY DEFINER` as a user who *does* have the appropriate update rights.